# Compute the distance between polyline (route) and marker in Google Maps API v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there any convenient way to compute the direct (shortest) distance between Polyline (the route generated by Google Directions) and markers that are NOT situated on that polyline?

The only way I found out is to cycle through `Polyline.getPath()` vertices manually to calculate the shortest distance but it seems to be a bit harsh:

```
var path = routes[0].overview_path;

for (var i = 0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
    var latLngA = new LatLng(data.points[i].lat, data.points[i].lng);
    var shortest_distance = null;

    for (var j = 0; j < path.length; j++) {
        var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, path[i]);

        if (shortest_distance == null || distance < shortest_distance) {
            shortest_distance = distance;
        }
    }

    console.log(data.points[i].point_title, shortest_distance);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am writing an android app , which should give alert when user goes 100 metre out of current route . I  think calculating distance from route to current position and then comparing it with 100 metre solves my problem . Would you guide me in doing this . Actually , problem is I don't understand , how do i get second coordinate from which distance will be calculated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the Google Maps API  does not give you a way to do this easily. And unfortunately, the algorithm you use will not give an accurate answer, because it gives the distance from the marker to the closest vertex on the path, not the closest point on the polyline itself, which will usually not be one of the points.

If you really need an accurate calculation, the best option I know of is to use the Javascript Topology Suite ([JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts)). JSTS has a ton of geographic formulas for calculating this sort of thing. That means converting the polyline returned from the directions API into a JSTS object and calling the right utility function. Not trivial, but not too difficult either.

Comment: I'm getting one back from the dead here, but how would you go about converting the polyline to a JSTS object? JSTS doesn't seem to have a good documentation, or at least I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Use turf - modular geospatial analysis engine.
https://turfjs.org/docs/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).