# Get distance along polyline from lat/lng point

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js

I'm rendering a polyline on a Google map with data that looks like this:

```
data = [
  {
    distance: 3.45,
    lat: 37.37112776376307,
    lng: -122.13909476995468,
  },
  ...
];
```

When hovering over the polyline, I can get the `lat`/`lng` coordinates and I want to get the distance along the line based on those coordinates.

I haven't found an easy way to do this with the Maps API. I want the distance from the start to an arbitrary point *along the polyline*; most answers I've found deal simply with the (shortest) distance between two points, not along a predefined route.

My other thought was to use D3 (which I'm using to draw some related charts) to bisect the data and get the distance. However, I can't figure out how to bisect based on two data points (`lat`+ `lng`).

Any advice on how to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

EDIT: In my data, `distance` is the cumulative distance traveled at the given coordinates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate the geo position at given time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25562799/calculate-the-geo-position-at-given-time)

Comment: I am not familiar with the Google Maps API, but how is this distance determined? Does it have a direction (the next point)? If the hovering position on the polyline is in the middle of two points, and you don't know how the topography is distributed along the path, you will have to add up the distances and approximate between the last point and the cursor.

Comment: If you look at my answer to the linked question, it uses a third party library function `GetPointAtDistance` that does just that.

Comment: @geocodezip: I want the inverse of that answer, ie: `GetDistanceAtPoint` rather than `GetPointAtDistance`

Comment: [The answer is here. It works!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69225130/16937916)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I was hoping the Maps API would have a method along the lines of

```
polyLine.computeDistanceBetween(point1, point2);
```

but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I ended up breaking down the problem similar to how @Mark_M describes above:

1. [Find the point on the polyline closest to the hovered point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9777980/882638)

   ```
   function getIndexOfNearestPoint(path, hoveredPoint) {
     let index = -1;
     let minDistance = 1000;

     path.forEach((pointOnPath, idx) => {
       const dist = window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
         hoveredPoint,
         pointOnPath
       );

       if (dist < minDistance){
         minDistance = dist;
         index = idx;
       }
     });

     return index;
   }
   ```
2. Calculate the distance between 2 points on the polyline

   ```
   function getDistanceAlongPath(path, startIndex, endIndex) {
     let distance = 0;
     for (let ii = startIndex; ii < endIndex; ii++) {
       distance += window.google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
         path[ii],
         path[ii + 1]
       );
     }
     return distance;
   }
   ```

Putting it together to find the cumulative distance from the start of the polyline to the hovered point:

```
polyline.addListener('mousemove', e => {
  const path = polyline.getPath().getArray();
  const hoveredPoint = e.latLng;
  const startIndex = 0;

  const endIndex = getIndexOfNearestPoint(path, hoveredPoint);
  const distance = getDistanceAlongPath(path, startIndex, endIndex);
});
```

Comment: I don't think this gets you *from the start to an arbitrary point along the polyline*. It gets you from the start to one of the points already on the poly line, right? If your cursor is half way between two points, you lose that distance, don't you?

Comment: That's true, but it's enough for my purposes (+/- 30 ft). I can increase the polyline density to increase precision if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this (and a lot more) using the [Turf](http://turfjs.org) library.

With Turf you could break your problem into a few smaller problems —

- Find the exact place on the line nearest the cursor
- Create a polyline from  the start to that point
- Measuring the length of that polyline.

For example, here is a route through several cities from Chicago to Portland, Maine and we want to figure out how far it is to Schenectady which is near the line between Syracuse and Boston but isn't on our route:

```
const turf = require('@turf/helpers')
const lineSlice = require('@turf/line-slice')
const pointOnLine = require('@turf/point-on-line')
const lineDistance = require('@turf/line-distance')

var route = turf.lineString([
[-87.627453, 41.853555], // Chicago
[-87.389126, 41.587682], // Gary IN
[-81.674692, 41.420385], // Clevland
[-76.077655, 42.988040], // Syracuse
[-71.066601, 42.323782], // Boston
[-70.277662, 43.627106]  // Portland, ME
]);

var Schenectady = turf.point([-73.899115, 42.815089]); //Schenectady

var snapped = pointOnLine(route, Schenectady, 'miles');
var sliced = lineSlice(route.geometry.coordinates[0], snapped, route);
var length = lineDistance(sliced, 'miles');

console.log(length) // => 736.8317888716095
```

This agrees pretty closely with Google's 810 mile route that is not all straight lines.

Comment: The way you broke it down makes sense, but was hoping not to add another 3rd-party lib. I posted an answer on how I did it with the Maps API and plain JS.

Answer (score 0):

If your data set is just a list of `lat/lng`, you could use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27943/7796750) to calculate the gap between each point according to the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (shortest distance over the earth's surface).

Comment: I don't want the shortest distance between the two points, though. I want the distance *along the polyline* between the two points, ie: the cumulative distance from the start to whatever point is being hovered over on the polyline. This is often not the shortest distance.

Comment: Isn't the [polyline](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) just a list of segments? Then your cursor should be on a line and you would do *the sum of the length between each point until the one being hovered*, but maybe I misunderstood something? Please answer by editing your question with more details, a demo link would be nice.

Comment: Actually, this is more or less what I ended up doing, though using Maps's `computeDistanceBetween` method.